# Ampscript Multiply

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

so... I was trying use the multiply option but an error appears:

An error occurred when attempting to evaluate an Multiply function call. See inner exception for details.
Invalid value specified for function parameter.
Function Name: Multiply
Parameter Name: Value2
Parameter Ordinal: 2
Parameter Type: Numeric

```
%%[ 
VAR @saldo, @nombre, @copy, @conversion, @reward 

SET @nombre = AttributeValue ('nombre') 
SET @conversion = '0.01' 
SET @reward = AttributeValue ('ultimos_puntos_ganados') 
SET @saldo = Multiply(@conversion, @reward) 
SET @copy = Concat(“Recibiste”, @saldo, " MXN -” ,@reward, “puntos- que puedes usar inmediatamente para ahorrar en tu próximo viaje.”)

]%%
```

Any clue?

Comment: Can you delete the space between attributevalue and the bracket, it might be the reason. `AttributeValue('nombre')` another thing is that you set conversion as a string. Try to write `set @conversion = 0.01` Also it might work with the ' because variables are loosely typed. If it still doesn’t work we might need to know how nombre and ultimos.... are retrieved (source and examples)

Comment: Hi Johannes, it didn't work :( We receive the data via API and the data type is numeric. Do you think that could cause trouble?

Comment: I would verify the value you are getting for 'ultimos_puntos_ganados'  I suggest commenting out the multiply part and print the value for @reward and review what you are trying to multiple

Answer (score 2):

That is a quite unconventional problem - There is a problem with the **quotation marks** in your CONCAT line.

```
SET @copy = Concat(“Recibiste”, @saldo, " MXN -” ,@reward, “puntos- que puedes usar 
inmediatamente para ahorrar en tu próximo viaje.”)
```

As you can see, some of them are not identical (you got 2 different types of quotation marks):

> “quote...”

and

> "quote..." (You're supposed to use these)

so instead, change this line to a one with fixed quotation marks, like this:

```
SET @copy = Concat("Recibiste", @saldo, " MXN -" ,@reward, "puntos- que puedes usar 
inmediatamente para ahorrar en tu próximo viaje.")
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

I changed some “ to " in @copy but since we don't know if its working we need you to give us the output from this[execute this on a cloudpage or somewhere]:

```
%%[ 
VAR @saldo, @nombre, @copy, @conversion, @reward 

SET @nombre = AttributeValue('nombre')
Output(Concat("Nombre value is: ",@nombre,"<br>"))
/* You should try '0.01' when this doesnt work on conversion */
SET @conversion = 0.01
Output(Concat("conversion value is: ",@conversion,"<br>"))
SET @reward = AttributeValue('ultimos_puntos_ganados')
Output(Concat("reward value is: ",@reward,"<br>"))
SET @saldo = Multiply(@conversion, @reward) 
Output(Concat("saldo value is: ",@saldo,"<br>"))
SET @copy = Concat("Recibiste", @saldo, " MXN -" ,@reward, "puntos- que puedes usar inmediatamente para ahorrar en tu próximo viaje.")
Output(Concat("copy value is: ",@copy,"<br>"))

]%%
```